# How to search within a specific area in Google Search

Tags: google-search, search-engine

Is there any way to search for some information on sites belonging to a particular area without specifying the area name as a keyword in the search string?

or

Is there any way to search for some information that belongs to a specific area?

**For example**: I want to search "dance class" in "Andheri, Mumbai, India". So I'll have to search like "dance class andheri mumbai". Or I'll have to go for some yellow pages search site.

**Why not Yellow Pages?**

Yellow page search is better when I am searching for some product or service. But my search can be anything like some news, images, person etc

**Why dont I want to specify area in the search string?**

Search engines take it as keyword. And they'll search for pages where my actual search string and place both appears or at least one.

Comment: Which search engine?

Comment: I prefer google. but any one

Comment: You should probably consider using a specialized local search tool. What you're asking for isn't possible unless heavily customized

Comment: Any update on this, I am searching for something similar.https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151031/google-search-for-multiple-countries-region-area

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.

`dance class near Andheri, Mumbai, India` will return listings above the search results

A second way would be to point your browser to google.co.in then set your location in the sidebar. The closest I got was "Andheri East, Maharashtra" (which seems to be the correct way to phrase it).

Web results itself are harder, how would one check whether a site that has dance classes is located in Andheri East, Maharashtra without checking some location within the text displayed on the site?

Comment: site's IP address

Comment: @articlestack: The ip address of the site, may not be helpful. The small business may have a very small website sitting on a host in the next town, or even across the country.

Comment: @phwd, yes you are correct. But I was hopping any search engine who maintains some sort of database based on AI algos to distinguish sites on the basis of their language, ip addr, visitor ip addr etc. I though Google can do it easily.

Comment: Based on your factors mentioned it's still not a cut and dry method. A site can have most of its vistors for location X but does that necessarily mean that site is a service for location X?