# Google search for multiple countries/region/area?

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to search Google for multiple locations at the same time, for example the African continent, or multiple countries.
There is the possibility to do it for a single location. `gl=sa` in the search string will search in Saudi Arabia. Is it possible to add other countries?